# Refreshing grid not working after store.sync();

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have added successfully data to server and get json back so that I have success = true. After adding, my grid doesn't sync data (just after refreshing with F5). In handler for success I've put:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('Workers');
store.sync();
```

I've checked and I really get store Workers but the sync is not working.

I think that when I reload data in store, data in grid should be also reloaded.

I've tried this too:

```
Ext.getCmp('workerlist').getView().refresh();
```

**I've tried all examples from stackoverflow. :)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure you did...

`sync();` is not the correct method for loading data. You should try

```
var store = Ext.getStore('Workers');
store.load();
```

A grid binds itself to a store, so if you reload the store the grid will always do so but the grid will never causing a load on the store when calling `refresh()` on it. You may also try to get the grid and access the store from there like `Ext.getCmp('my-grid').store.load();`

Comment: LOL ... sra u r killing me :)