# Grid refreshing: Why does the Store load before the form is submitted?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a Form that adds objects to a grid. My grid is connected to a Store that has a proxy. I'm adding in new entries to my database via the proxy. I can successfully create new entries, but I'm having trouble updating my grid in a timely fashion. This is the submit button from my Form:

```
buttons: [{
        text: 'Submit',
        formBind: true, /* only enabled once the form is valid*/
        handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm()
            if(form.isValid()) {
                form.submit()
            }
            Ext.getCmp('grid').getStore().load({
                callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                    console.log(records);
                }
            })
        }
    }]
```

When this runs in my app, the load request is called before the form is submitted when I view the order of Network requests in Chrome dev tools. When I press the submit button again, the grid then refreshes displaying all of my data plus the previous added entry, but not the entry that was just added. Thus my grid is always one request behind in the sync.

I've tried calling `sync()` and also calling `load()` on my Grid's Store, but to no avail. [According to what I've read though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466179/refreshing-grid-not-working-after-store-sync), load() should be sufficient to update my grid. I think the order of the requests is what's messing things up, but I don't know how to fix it...

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can make sure that load is getting called after form.submit() would be to call it like:

```
myForm.getForm().submit({

    success: function(form, action) {
       store.load();
    }

});
```

Having said that, i think form.submit() in your code should get called before store.load(). Have you tried debugging in chrome to see what gets executed first?

Comment: Yeah, debugging in Chrome shows that the url of my proxy gets calls before the url for creating a new entry is called. I'll try what you've suggested and get back to you in a few minutes

Comment: I had to change my response to the form POST request [to respond with a JSON object `{"success": true, "msg": "some message" } `](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-submit) before the function in the success property was called, but the refresh works fine now! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

The 'submit' method is asynchronous, meaning that it does not stop the execution of subsequent lines in your handler method. Right after making the submit request to the server, the store is loading the records. So, the two operations are not related and the second can get done before the first even hit the database (depending on your server business rules). The update operations tends to have more cost.

This form's 'success' method mentioned in the answer above takes a config object. By placing any code inside 'success' method (there are other methods as well: failure, callback,...see the docs), you ensure that the first operation is made, and then you can safely load your grid.

Almost all methods in the Ext.data package are asynchronous.